# Regular expression which accept both email address and 10 digit phone number

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, regex, nsregularexpression

I need an regular expression which accept 10 digit phone number and also email address with one input textfield.

Example :

**Phonenumber: 1234567890**

**Emailaddress : somename@somecompany.com or somename@somecompany.in**

Can any one advice me to get that regular expression.
@KiranMac123

Comment: you mean this `^(?:\d{10}|\w+@\w+\.\w{2,3})$`

Comment: Post that as an answer @AvinashRaj, that looks right to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below regex to match the 10 digit phone number or an email address.

```
^(?:\d{10}|\w+@\w+\.\w{2,3})$
```

Comment: `\w+@\w+\.\w{2,3}` is nowhere close to good enough to match all valid email addresses.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/201378/9530 for why.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply do this:

```
^(.+@.+|\d{10})$
```

Note that this regex does not match all valid email addresses. And it does match some that are not valid. But for most cases it's good enough.

Unless you have a good reason, I would strongly advice against using a regex to check email addresses. [Read here why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48055434/6699433)