# How to set the count of characters in several groups of regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex, email

I have a regexp, which checks the email addresses.

And how can I set the max count of symbols of whole block after @.

```
export const EMAILREGEX =
/^[ ]*[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]{1,64}@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*[ ]*$/;
```

Comment: _“I have a regexp, which checks the email addresses”_ - so far, so [_bad_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48170419/10955263) … _“the max count of symbols of whole block after @”_ - a) why, b) what maximum value would you want to set it to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use positive look ahead just after `@` character in your regex to specify the min max length of part that follows `@` character. Let's say you want it to be minimum 10 characters and maximum 20, then you can write `(?=.{10,20}$)` just after `@` in your regex. Here is how your regex should look like,

```
/^[ ]*[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]{1,64}@(?=.{10,20}$)[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*[ ]*$/;
```

Here, `(?=)` is called [positive look ahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and `.{10,20}$` means any character minimum 10 and maximum 20 followed by end of string signified by `$`

You can also refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups) post for getting familiar with how look arounds work.