# Email Regular Expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

I've taken the regular expressions from a website some time ago, and now I'm trying to fix some issues but I'm terrible with regular expressions, I'm just learning, any help would be appreciated.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
function validateEmail(email) {

    var reg1 = /^([a-zA-Z0-9])+\@([a-zA-Z0-9])+\.+([a-zA-Z0-9])+$/; // example@mail.com
    var reg2 = /^([a-zA-Z0-9])+\@([a-zA-Z0-9])+\.+([a-zA-Z0-9])+\.+([a-zA-Z0-9])+$/; // example@mail.test.com
    var reg3 = /^([a-zA-Z0-9])+\@([a-zA-Z0-9])+\.+([a-zA-Z0-9])+$/; // example.test@mail.test.com
    var reg4 = /^([a-zA-Z0-9])+\.+@([a-zA-Z0-9])+\.+([a-zA-Z0-9])+\.+([a-zA-Z0-9])+$/; // example.test@mail.com

    return reg1.test(email) || reg2.test(email) || reg3.test(email) || reg4.test(email)
  }
```

I need to accept mails in this formats:

```
example@mail.com
example@mail.test.com
example.test@mail.test.com
example.test@mail.com
```

reg1 and reg2 are working, reg3 and reg4 are not working.

Last edit:

I've tried to fix it like this, didn't work properly neither:

function validateEmail(email) {

```
    var reg1 = /^([a-zA-Z0-9])+\@([a-zA-Z0-9])+\.+([a-zA-Z0-9])+$/; // example@mail.com
    var reg2 = /^([a-zA-Z0-9])+\@([a-zA-Z0-9])+\.+([a-zA-Z0-9])+\.+([a-zA-Z0-9])+$/; // example@mail.test.com
    var reg3 = /^([a-zA-Z0-9])+\.+([a-zA-Z0-9])+\@([a-zA-Z0-9])+\.+([a-zA-Z0-9])+\.+([a-zA-Z0-9])+$/; // example.test@mail.test.com
    var reg4 = /^([a-zA-Z0-9])+\.+([a-zA-Z0-9])+\@([a-zA-Z0-9])+\.+([a-zA-Z0-9])+$/; // example.test@mail.com

    return reg1.test(email) || reg2.test(email) || reg3.test(email) || reg4.test(email)
  }
```

Comment: What are you expecting it to do and what is it doing?

Comment: So what is wrong?

Comment: Can you please describe the issues you're trying to fix?  We can't guess.

Comment: I've edited, sorry about that.

Comment: *What am I doing wrong here?* ... Using regex for email address validation? See [Can it cause harm to validate email addresses with a regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48055431/215552). https://davidcel.is/posts/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/

Comment: Okay so you have not stated what is wrong still.

Comment: I need to accept emails in the 4 formats I've just added in the last edit.

Comment: reg1 and reg2 is working, reg3 and reg4 are NOT working...

Comment: Have you tried just using `<input type="email">`?

Comment: @Scott Marcus I am using input type="email" alredy. I just don't understand regular expressions and need some help with it

Comment: Understand. But, wanted you to know about it because it doesn't require any validation. The validation is built in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can validate those simple email formats with a single regex:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?@[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+){1,2}$
```

- `^[a-zA-Z0-9]+` - start with one or more alphanumeric chars
- `(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?` - optionally allow a period followed by one or more alphanumeric chars
- `@` - require the @ symbol
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` - require one or more alphanumeric chars
- `(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+){1,2}$` - require one or two more sequences of a period followed by alphanumeric chars to end the string

https://regex101.com/r/wREGo4/1

Comment: That's an answer that I can finally understand and meets my requirements. I appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: @sisorken You're welcome. I know regex can be cryptic especially when copy+paste+praying from a random site :)

Comment: @sisorken I'm sorry to hear that but I'm glad you are recovering. regex101 is a really superb site to exercise your regex skills and expand your understanding. Much of the issue that I find with regex is not so much "What does this syntax do?" but more so "Why did the person write the syntax in this specific sequence? What scenario are they trying to account for?" Assuming your sample emails were all inclusive then the "What scenario are they trying to account for?" was pre-answered :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't validate emails beyond the simple

```
*@*.*
```

You send a validation email to the address and require them to click the validation link. You WILL get it wrong and lock people out of entering their email to your system.

Comment: Hello. It's not for login, I don't send any validation email and I don't need to.

Comment: You are not going to get a regex that cover every email possible.

Comment: This is the right answer (+1), except that in javascript you have to use `.+@.+`