# Is it safe to use sed to remove private data from logs

Tags: logging, kubernetes, sed

As part our desire to avoid unnecessary Personally Identifiable Information collection, I would like to prevent email addresses from being logged and later extend this to other info.

As [we want to treat logs as streams](https://12factor.net/logs), the obvious solution seems to be using sed. However I can't find any information on whether or not this is a good idea.

Presumably I can just pipe the service output through something like

```
#!/bin/sed -rf
# Obfuscate email addresses (e.g username@email.com => ####@email.com).
s/[[:alnum:]_+%.-]+@/###@/
```

And not have to worry about email addresses finding their way into the logs.

1. Would this have some obvious negative consequence that I am missing? (Logs are new-line delimeted JSON, Average length 800 chars).
2. Is there some standard way I could configure this at the kubernetes node/cluster level?

(I understand that this email regex [is not comprehensive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48055431/can-it-cause-harm-to-validate-email-addresses-with-a-regex), there would still be the assumption that the logs need to be treated securely. I'm looking more for a belt and braces approach)

Comment: `the obvious solution seems to be using sed`: No this is not an obvious solution. What sort of logging facade are you using, is it `slf4j` ?

Comment: Just an email terminus as commonly used on web forms can probably be matched just fine with a regex; the hard parts are in the decorations allowed around the address by RFC5322. There are also corner cases which are not in common use, like "quoted string"@example.com but if you are just cleaning out logs, you are probably fine with less than 100% accuracy.

Comment: You probably want `#!/bin/sed -rf` where the `!` is crucial. (Less crucially, check the spelling of "obfuscate".)

Comment: A trickier problem is people who fill in all kinds of non-email information because they can't read forms. What should you do about the email address `the body is buried on lot 123 on main street`?

Comment: @anubhava, sed was obvious to me as I amd dealing with the log stream. This isn't something I want littered through my application code.

Comment: @tripleee that wouldn't be an issue because it is not personally identifiable or relating to living persons and so outside the remit of the GDPR

Comment: A few remarks: within `[...]`, you don't have to escape, so backslashes are treated literally; the `-` should be the first or last character in the bracket expression; you could use `[[:alnum:]]` instead of `[A-Za-z0-9]`; you seem to include a literal `+` right before the `@`, is that intentional?

Comment: Thanks @BenjaminW. for the sed regex tips. Updated.